# Symfony: using getPartial() in a third party library (in $SFROOT/lib folder)

Tags: php, events, symfony1

I am using the events system in Symfony 1.3.8.

I am writing logic for the event handlers. As part of my logic, I may need to send email. I therefore need to get the appropriate partial for the email to be sent.

What is the best way to do this?

I have this so far:

```
class MyEventHandler
{
    public static function handleFooEvent(sfEvent $event)
    {
         // I need to get partial here
         // $body = $this->getPartial('somemodule', 'foo', $params);
    }
}
```

I notice that getPartial() is implemented in sfAction like this:

```
  public function getPartial($templateName, $vars = null)
  {
    $this->getContext()->getConfiguration()->loadHelpers('Partial');

    $vars = null !== $vars ? $vars : $this->varHolder->getAll();

    return get_partial($templateName, $vars);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To load an helper from anywhere in your application, you can use the following:

```
sfProjectConfiguration::getActive()->loadHelpers("Partial", "Url", "MyHelper");
```

Then you can get the needed partial just with:

```
get_partial('somemodule/somepartial', $params)
```